# split tabs string into different columns

Tags: python, pyspark, split, palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

In my foundry environment, I have a pyspark dataset with only one column called "data".

Each row has a string that looks like a TSV. Each row has a value like this:

```
ott-akamai-logs-processor   srv 2023-07-29 17:46:50.134 2023-07-29 17:46:49.358     unstruct    103b9271-777        ott node-3.13.1 ssc-2.8.2-kinesis   snowplow-enrich-kinesis-3.7.0       3.65.234.x              12345679    DE  HE  Karachi 60313   50.1188 8.6843  Malta                                                                                                                                       {"schema":"iglu:com.xxx/1-0-0","data":{"schema":"xxx/hls_manifest_requested/jsonschema/1-0-1","data":{"channel":"bildtv-broadcast","session_id":"xxx","request_id":"xxx","total_bytes":351,"referrer":"^","geo_country":"DE","geo_state":"Berlin","geo_city":"-","variant_name":"6.m3u8"}}}                                                                         snowplow-nodejs-tracker/3.13.1                                                                                                                                                      Europe/Berlin               2023-07-29 17:46:49.281         {"schema":"xxx/contexts/jsonschema/1-0-1","data":[{"schema":"iglu:nl.basjes/yauaa_context/jsonschema/1-0-4","data":{"deviceBrand":"Unknown","deviceName":"Unknown","operatingSystemVersionMajor":"??","layoutEngineNameVersion":"Unknown ??","operatingSystemNameVersion":"Unknown ??","agentInformationEmail":"Unknown","networkType":"Unknown","webviewAppNameVersionMajor":"Unknown ??","layoutEngineNameVersionMajor":"Unknown ??","operatingSystemName":"Unknown","agentVersionMajor":"3","layoutEngineVersionMajor":"??","webviewAppName":"Unknown","deviceClass":"Unknown","agentNameVersionMajor":"Snowplow-Nodejs-Tracker 3","operatingSystemNameVersionMajor":"Unknown ??","webviewAppVersionMajor":"??","operatingSystemClass":"Unknown","webviewAppVersion":"??","layoutEngineName":"Unknown","agentName":"Snowplow-Nodejs-Tracker","agentVersion":"3.13.1","layoutEngineClass":"Unknown","agentNameVersion":"Snowplow-Nodejs-Tracker 3.13.1","operatingSystemVersion":"??","agentClass":"Special","layoutEngineVersion":"??","agentInformationUrl":"Unknown"}},{"schema":"iglu:com.snowplowanalytics.snowplow/ua_parser_context/jsonschema/1-0-0","data":{"useragentFamily":"Other","useragentMajor":null,"useragentMinor":null,"useragentPatch":null,"useragentVersion":"Other","osFamily":"Other","osMajor":null,"osMinor":null,"osPatch":null,"osPatchMinor":null,"osVersion":"Other","deviceFamily":"Other"}}]}        2023-07-29 17:46:09.938 com.axelspringer.ott    hls_manifest_requested  jsonschema  1-0-1       2023-07-29 17:46:09.938
```

Here, things are separated by tabs. For each tab separation, I want to put the values into different columns. How can I do so?

```
def unnamed_1(my_df):
    df = my_df

    return df
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the split function in spark to accomplish this:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.split.html

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

split_col = f.split(df['data'], '\t')

formatted_df = (
    df
    .withColumn('column_a', split_col.getItem(0))
    .withColumn('column_b', split_col.getItem(1))
    .withColumn('column_c', split_col.getItem(2))
    # ...
    .drop('data')
)
```

If you have a list of the desired columns in the correct order, you can automate it with iteration:

```py
columns = [
    'column_a',
    'column_b',
    'column_c',
    # ...
]

formatted_df = df
for i in range(len(columns)):
    column_name = columns[i]
    column_values = split_col.getItem(i)
    formatted_df = formatted_df.withColumn(column_name, column_values)

formatted_df = formatted_df.drop('data')
```

If you're receiving this data as a properly formatted TSV you could instead use the delimiter option while reading in the data to parse this.

```py
df = (
    spark.read.format("csv")
    .option("delimiter", "\t")
    .load('data.tsv')
)
```

Comment: In this case, we're manually specifying each getItem. Is there a more automatic way?

Comment: @x89 if you've got a full list of the columns represented in the tab separated field you could iterate over the list and assign the columns that way.  I've updated the answer to show one way to accomplish that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pandas.read_csv` for that:

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

string = 'ott-akamai-logs-processor   srv 2023-07-29 17:46:50.134 2023-07-29 17:46:49.358     unstruct    103b9271-777        ott node-3.13.1 ssc-2.8.2-kinesis   snowplow-enrich-kinesis-3.7.0       3.65.234.x              12345679    DE  HE  Karachi 60313   50.1188 8.6843  Malta                                                                                                                                       {"schema":"iglu:com.xxx/1-0-0","data":{"schema":"xxx/hls_manifest_requested/jsonschema/1-0-1","data":{"channel":"bildtv-broadcast","session_id":"xxx","request_id":"xxx","total_bytes":351,"referrer":"^","geo_country":"DE","geo_state":"Berlin","geo_city":"-","variant_name":"6.m3u8"}}}                                                                         snowplow-nodejs-tracker/3.13.1                                                                                                                                                      Europe/Berlin               2023-07-29 17:46:49.281         {"schema":"xxx/contexts/jsonschema/1-0-1","data":[{"schema":"iglu:nl.basjes/yauaa_context/jsonschema/1-0-4","data":{"deviceBrand":"Unknown","deviceName":"Unknown","operatingSystemVersionMajor":"??","layoutEngineNameVersion":"Unknown ??","operatingSystemNameVersion":"Unknown ??","agentInformationEmail":"Unknown","networkType":"Unknown","webviewAppNameVersionMajor":"Unknown ??","layoutEngineNameVersionMajor":"Unknown ??","operatingSystemName":"Unknown","agentVersionMajor":"3","layoutEngineVersionMajor":"??","webviewAppName":"Unknown","deviceClass":"Unknown","agentNameVersionMajor":"Snowplow-Nodejs-Tracker 3","operatingSystemNameVersionMajor":"Unknown ??","webviewAppVersionMajor":"??","operatingSystemClass":"Unknown","webviewAppVersion":"??","layoutEngineName":"Unknown","agentName":"Snowplow-Nodejs-Tracker","agentVersion":"3.13.1","layoutEngineClass":"Unknown","agentNameVersion":"Snowplow-Nodejs-Tracker 3.13.1","operatingSystemVersion":"??","agentClass":"Special","layoutEngineVersion":"??","agentInformationUrl":"Unknown"}},{"schema":"iglu:com.snowplowanalytics.snowplow/ua_parser_context/jsonschema/1-0-0","data":{"useragentFamily":"Other","useragentMajor":null,"useragentMinor":null,"useragentPatch":null,"useragentVersion":"Other","osFamily":"Other","osMajor":null,"osMinor":null,"osPatch":null,"osPatchMinor":null,"osVersion":"Other","deviceFamily":"Other"}}]}        2023-07-29 17:46:09.938 com.axelspringer.ott    hls_manifest_requested  jsonschema  1-0-1       2023-07-29 17:46:09.938'
tsvString = StringIO(string)
df = pd.read_csv(tsvString,sep='\t')
```